# Is there a way to cluster different machines running Tomcat instances

Tags: tomcat, amazon-ec2

I have setup multiple tomcat instances in a single machine to launch more threads, however, if I have to make use of 10 EC2 instances with Tomcat installed as a cluster, how would I achieve this. Any good resources to look at?

Comment: Same way you would do it in physical machines. See https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/cluster-howto.html. Note that Tomcat clustering is only necessary for session replication. Otherwise, you can just put all 10 machines behind an ELB (see http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/). Both approaches can be combined, as described in the Tomcat docs referenced above.

Comment: Not sure the question is really for Cluster, or just load balancer.

Comment: @BMW.... Kind of load balancer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirmed, @sri asked for load balancer in AWS. Please go through the document [aws elb](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/)

> Elastic Load Balancing automatically distributes incoming application traffic across multiple Amazon EC2 instances in the cloud. It enables you to achieve greater levels of fault tolerance in your applications, seamlessly providing the required amount of load balancing capacity needed to distribute application traffic.

Some my clients didn't use ELB and prefer to use the free tool `haproxy` or licensed F5 to do the load balancer, you an also have a try.